# Integrating FBReader with custom code

Tags: android

Hi i am going to integrate FBReader Source code with my custom apps so i want that when i click on a book it should be open directly without going to library so please can any one tell where should i change the code in FBReader or where can i put the book path directly in FBReader source code.

I want to assign the book path of sdcard as 
String path=name=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"bookname";
so where can i put this path to directly open the book.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can change the path in `FbReader.java` file in package name

```
org.geometerplus.android.fbreader
```